I dont record data
I am trying to add data to an existing database, but they (data) are not recorded, but they do not give errors.
I tried to change 1 code (with Post and GET requests at once) for 2 separate codes (with Post and GET) , please help.
Thank you in advance.
My main file:
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import parse_images
import sqlite3


Host_NAME = 'localhost'
Host_Port = 80
app = Flask(__name__)



conn = sqlite3.connect('reg.db')
c = conn.cursor()


c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reg
             (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
             username TEXT,
             email TEXT NOT NULL,
             password TEXT NOT NULL)''')


@app.route('/reg', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reg():

   if request.method == 'POST':
      if request.values.get('txt'):
         conn = sqlite3.connect('reg.db')
         cursor = conn.cursor()
         cursor.execute("INSERT INTO reg ('username', 'email', 'password') VALUES (?,?,?)",(request.values.get('txt'),request.values.get('email'), request.values.get('password')))
         conn.commit()
         conn.close()
   return render_template('reg.html')


@app.route("/Login")
def login():
    return render_template('Login.html')

@app.route('/pay')
def pay():
    return render_template("pay.html")


@app.route("/")
def index():
    # Fetch the list of image URLs
    image_urls = parse_images.parse_images('https://ap-pro.ru/')

    # Insert the images into the index.html file
    with open('templates\index.html', "r") as file:
        html_content = file.read()

    # Replace the placeholder with the actual image URLs
    html_content = html_content.replace("INSERT_IMAGE_TAGS", ",".join(image_urls))

    # Write the modified HTML content back to the file
    with open('templates\index.html', "w") as file:
        file.write(html_content)

    # Render the modified index.html file
    return render_template("index.html", parse_images=parse_images.parse_images)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="5050")

If necessary, I can attach the HTML file of the registration form
I changed the 3-way code

Your code that adds to the database is gated behind two if statements: request.method == 'POST' and request.values.get('txt').  If either of those statements are false, the database code will not run.  Have you tried logging/printing those values to make sure they are what you expect?
